# how to add my 'no' or 'id' in the url using javascript function(onclick)

Tags: javascript, php, json

here is my function

```
function swipe2() {
   window.open ( 'edit.php?no=','newwindow')
}
```

my php ( I skip some)

```
for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++)
{
   if ($i == $total_results) { 
      break; 
   }
   echo "<tr>";
   echo ("<td><img src='edit.jpg' width='20' alt='Edit' title='EDIT DATA' onClick='swipe2();'style='cursor: pointer;'". mysql_result($result, $i, 'no')." ></td>");'

   echo '<td><a href="delete.php?no='  . mysql_result($result, $i, 'no') . ' "><img src="delete.jpg" width="20" alt="Delete" title="DELETE DATA"></a></td>';

   echo strtoupper('<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'no') . '</td>');

   echo strtoupper('<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'CPUname') . '</td>');
}    
echo "</tr>";   
echo "</table>";
```

the problem is my function `swipe2()` `edit.php?no=` dont add number.

thanks in advance..

help pls

Comment: try `window.open ( 'edit.php?no='+valueyouwanttosend,'newwindow')`

Comment: the value i want to send is in the php, my `delete.php?no= ` is displaying a number defends on what i click but my edit not displaying  because it is in the function its not diplaying number `edit.php?no=`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ("<td><img src='edit.jpg' width='20' alt='Edit' title='EDIT DATA'         onClick='swipe2('' + . mysql_result($result, $i, 'no'). + '');'style='cursor:            pointer;'". mysql_result($result, $i, 'no')." ></td>");'

function swipe2(id) { window.open ( 'edit.php?no='+id,'newwindow') }
```

the swipe2 function need add the id,so pass it to the function and add it there.

Comment: the new window wont run

Comment: Does it compile with all `'` quotation signs